# TensorBoard: How to add email link?

Tags: tensorboard

Goal: Would like to add a link in the TensorBoard GUI that when clicked, allows user to send us an email.

I grepped through the entire code base and did not find any hooks or links or tests that supports any references to any email system.

I'm looking for something like this:

`<div id="sendEmail">
  We would like to hear from you.  Please contact us at: 
  <a href="mailto:xxx@yyy.com">xxx@yyy.com</a>
</div>`

When I include a link to an email address in the TensorBoard HTML file, then compile, I get the following bazel compiler error message:

`ERROR: file.html: Referenced mailto:xxx@yyy.com (/path/mailto:xxx@yyy.com) without depending on a web_library() rule providing it`